# nm-applet in xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, network-manager

Previously I was connected to Internet via a router but the other day i tried Ethernet i.e direct connection. And since i was required to use my password and username so i used sudo pppoeconf command in a command line to connect. I am connected successfully but the problem is nm applet is not showing I am connected. When i am clicking on for information in nm applet it is showing that ERROR DISPLAYING CONNECTION INFORMATION AND NO VALID ACTIVE CONNECTIONS FOUND. The arrow marks of nm-applet are even dim not lighted which one gets to see while connected to network..

I am unable to get what's the matter and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`pppeoconf` writes directly to `/etc/interfaces`, and network-manager doesn't like that.

Interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces` are no longer controlled by network-manager.
You could change 'managed' to 'true' in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file, but for some reason I forgot it's not recommended.

I'd remove the entries from  `/etc/interfaces` and use network-manager to create the connection.